# Closing/flagging UI slows down review process

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, user-interface, usability

The UI for closing and flagging questions needs to improve. Right now, if you're doing 50 close votes reviews per day, these faults in the UI will slow you down/irritate you mildly:

**Clicking the labels**
The action element labels are inline. Only their text descendants are clickable.

[image: showing where the labels currently flow]
*Inline elements are shy*

If the labels were **block** elements, one could click the label block instead.

[image: illustration of where how the labels could flow, were they block elements]
*Block elements invading the space they need*

Add `cursor: pointer;` for bonus points.

Adding insult (I kid) to injury, the action description, `.action-desc` has `margin`. Margins are not clickable, whereas `padding` would be perfectly acceptable and make it more clickable.

**No feedback on label hover**

The fix is real easy, just call your favourite designer and do something like this:

```
.action-list label:hover { background: peanut-butter; }
```

**Confusing dialog header**

The dialog header (Closing -> Off-topic) is also serving as breadcrumb. Pick one, please. Or, leave the header alone and feature a permanent breadcrumb.

**Where is the action button?**

Move "Vote to close" action button so it is aligned with the radio elements. This is just, like, my opinion.

Other than that, it's very rewarding to review stuff.